# How do you seamlessly integrate a third party library into Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, winapi

I want to take libFoobar/lib and libFoobar/include and tell VS2017 to make compiling and linking with them work **by default** for **all** projects.

In earlier versions there was a global setting for compiler directories but I believe they deprecated that and made it completely project level.

You can manually add a third party library to a project by configuring its project settings
Under C/C++ / additional include directories and linker / input / additional dependencies.

I don't want to have to store or memorize the names and locations of all of the .lib files or /include directories that I might need and manually re-enter them every time I start a new project or have to recreate an existing project.

There may be a way to create and maintain a project *template* which would be a solution.

You can add .libs to the project from the source code via #pragma comment(lib, "libFoobar.lib").  The most convenient overall method that I've got so far is to add /libFoobar/lib to the PATH variable, add the libs via #pragma to each header file, and manually add the /include directory to each project.  But that's a hack.

I did try to use "INCLUDE" and "LIBPATH" environment variables but they did not exist and adding them did nothing:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/cl-environment-variables?view=vs-2019

They might be valid on 2019 only.

Comment: Good question. Although I will just say that I support Microsoft's decision to make this harder. Blanketing every project with a bunch of dependencies you may or may not need seems like a bad idea. You suggest the list is long, which is suspicious. Why don't you wrap up your multiple libraries into _one_ library that you can use in each project that needs them all? Then your workload is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, project templates are a thing, and should accomplish this.

Here's some documentation I found by Googling "VS project templates":

- [How to: Create project templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Interesting!  It didn't occur to me until I had finished writing this question or I would have researched it.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: A better way is to use Property Sheets. They can be incorporated into *any* project, and only change/set those settings that are actually required. See [Share or reuse Visual Studio project settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=vs-2019) for details.

Comment: @IInspectable By all means go ahead and write an answer with your alternative suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making project templates you can modify the default project property sheets.

Go to View->Other window->Property manager then open one of the nodes for the machine type you are working with (debug and release builds share the actual property sheet file). Right click on Microsoft.Cpp..user and select Properties, you can then make changes just like any other property sheet and the settings will be picked up by projects generated using the default wizards.

This is the replacement system for the mentioned prior global setting.

Comment: [We no longer recommend these files because they set properties for project configurations on a per-user, per-computer basis. Such "global" settings can interfere with builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/create-reusable-property-configurations?view=vs-2019) [...].